# Execute several python processes in terminal, each in its own window

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I'm trying to execute several python processes in a Linux terminal. A search on Stack Overflow led me to this simple solution:

```
$ python3 scr1pt1.py & python3 scr1pt2.py & python3 scr1pt3.py
```

Which works great. Now I'd now like to have each process run in its own Terminal (LXterminal, to be precise) window, or -better- tab.

Also, the scripts are meant to run continuously, this is why I need them is separated windows or tabs (to monitor them).

How would I go about making this work?

Answer (score 1):

From Python you can try something like this:

```
import os

for script in ["test1.py", "test2.py", "test3.py"]:
    os.system(f"gnome-terminal -- python3 {script}")
```

Where your scripts terminate like this (if you want to close the terminal window after execution):

```
# do stuff
exit(0)
```

e.g. test1.py

```
import time

print("test 1")
time.sleep(10)
exit(0)
```

On lxterminal try the code above with the `gnome-terminal -- python3 {script}` replaced with:

```
lxterminal -e python3 {script}
```

**Updated in response to comment:**
Run this from lxterminal e.g. `python3 test.py`

```
import os

for script in ["test1.py", "test2.py", "test3.py"]:
    os.system(f"lxterminal -e python3 {script}")
```

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that the scripts are meant to run continuously, this is why I need them is separated windows or tabs (to monitor them)

Comment: Should still work if you call the first python script (containing the code I posted) using the lxterminal command from lxterminal